# using Fortran Module from external files

Tags: module, fortran, gfortran, subroutine, geany

I would like to call subroutines contained in a module. the module is saved in a separate file with *my_mod.f95* filename.

```
module calc_mean
! this module contains two subroutines
implicit none
public :: calc_sum
public :: mean

contains
subroutine calc_sum(x,n,s)
! this subroutine calculates sum of elements of a vector
! x the vector
! n size of the vector
! s sum of elements of x

integer, intent(in):: n
real, intent(in):: x(n)
integer :: i
real, intent(out):: s
s=0
do i=1,n
s=s+x(i)
end do
end subroutine calc_sum
!
!
!
subroutine mean(x,n,xav)
! this subroutine calculates the mean of a vector
! x the vector
! n size of the vector
! xav mean of x

integer, intent(in):: n
real, intent(in):: x(n)
real, intent(out):: xav
real :: s
!
!
call calc_sum(x,n,s)
xav=s/n
end subroutine mean
end module calc_mean
```

I have the main program saved in a different file with *'my_program.f95'*

```
program find_mean
! this program calculates mean of a vector
use calc_mean
implicit none

! read the vector from a file
integer, parameter ::n=200
integer :: un, ierror
character (len=25):: filename
real :: x(n), xav
un=30
filename='randn.txt'
! 
OPEN (UNIT=un, FILE=filename, STATUS='OLD', ACTION='READ', IOSTAT=ierror)
read(un,*) x ! 
!
call mean(x,n,xav)

write (*,100) xav
100 format ('mean of x is', f15.8)
end program find_mean
```

when I compile the main program with *geany*, I got the following error message. Please, help me!

**
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cctnlPMO.o: in function `MAIN__': my_program.f08:(.text+0x1e1): undefined reference to` __calc_mean_MOD_mean'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

**

When I save both the main program and the module to the same file and run it, everything is fine.

Comment: Please show a complete program which shows the problem, and the compile and link lines you are using. At the very minimum we need the link command

Comment: Also show the command(s) you used to compile and link, looks like you didn't link the `my_mod.o` file

Comment: Is geany capable of building files in a specific order and then linking afterwards?  I've only ever used geany as an editor and built from the command line.

Comment: Still missing "command(s) you used to compile and link".

Comment: I didn't use any linking commands. I just compile the main program. Could you help to do that, if possible an option to run the linking and compilation on geany? thank you!

Comment: I don't have access to the geany program but I guess that it doesn't compile the file containing the module. I suggest you write a simple makefile which does compilation and linking in the correct order. Just search for "fortran makefile" on the internet.